# How can I write the HTML Rendered by a control to a string

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, render

For an E-Commerce system, after the order is placed I have a custom user control that displays the order details. I also want to write the same order details to an email so I want to write the contents of the user control out to a string that I can add to the body of the email.

I tried using RenderControl but, the none of the dynamically populated label controls on the user control were populated.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    OrderDetails1.RenderControl(htw);
    return sb.ToString();
```

I found somewhere else that I could add the control to a page and then write the output of the page to a string but this felt kludgy.

It seems like I should be able to capture the contents of the control when it is first rendered so that I don't have to repopulate it and re-render it. Anyone know how?

If not, what's the cleanest way to populate the control?

Comment: You need to DataBind() the control first?

Comment: You need to create an instance of the Page class and dynamically add/render your user control to it.  Then you can grab the rendered contents into a string, you can see an example here (3rd Code Example): http://encosia.com/boost-aspnet-performance-with-deferred-content-loading/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the `RenderControl` code was proper, I just needed to call the controls FillData() function to repopulate the controls from the database.

```
private string RenderOrderInfo()
{
    //TODO: Should be able to use RenderControl for this and delete everything beyond the 1st 3 lines
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    OrderDetails1.FillData();
    OrderDetails1.RenderControl(htw);
    return sb.ToString();
}
```